# How get redundancy for forwarder in ZMQ PUB/SUB?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

I tried and made run this [example](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/forwarder.html). It worked very well.

I can add as many publishers or subscribers as I want, everything will communicate thanks to the forwarder. My concern is about redundancy. If the forwarder does not respond anymore, nothing's gonna work until forwarder is up.

I found an [example](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter4/#High-Availability-Pair-Binary-Star-Pattern) for REQ/REP, but it can't be applied for PUB/SUB as subscribers. But idea is here.

Is there a way to have something similar in a pub/sub scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First read [this](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter4/) chapter.

In the beginning of it it states that these reliability patterns don't apply to PUB-SUB patterns due to its broadcast nature.
So you can either put in a out of band control/ack/ping path that you use to see if everything went ok, or you can use a REQ/ROUTER/REP pattern that supports these reliability tests.