# ZMQ Load Balancer with Multiple Brokers for Redundancy

Tags: cloud, load-balancing, zeromq, distributed-computing, redundancy

I need to design and implement a system for a data streaming application. I have read the [Load Balancer in ZMQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#A-Load-Balancing-Message-Broker) and it is almost exactly what I need.

[image]

What I need is that there should be no single point of failures in the system. However, in the given design, if the Load Balancer goes down for some reason, the whole system goes down. Is there a known pattern for adding redundancy for the broker in the middle? Have you ever implemented such a system with ZMQ?

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18345387

Comment: Also, if you continue reading the article you linked, it goes into clustering, which I think is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

We normally use ZMQ for communication between processes, but when it comes to process streams from different sources to different sinks we use [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/). It meets most of your requirements, including fault tolerance.

[image]